# Motivations behind NoSQL

Tags: database, data-structures, nosql

What are the main motivations behind the invention of NoSQL Databases?

Your point of view would help my research on NoSQL databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The no:sql(east) conference 2009 in Atlanta had a strong influence on the NoSQL debate. Its self-conception was "a conference of non-relational data stores", and its motto was "select fun, profit from real_world where relational=false;" [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#History)

"The most common interpretation of "NoSQL" is "non-relational", although NoSQL is not meant as anti-RDBMS, but emphasizes the advantages of Key-Value Stores, Document Databases, and Graph Databases". [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#History)

These data stores may not require fixed table schemas, and usually avoid join operations and typically [scale horizontally](http://These%20data%20stores%20may%20not%20require%20fixed%20table%20schemas,%20and%20usually%20avoid%20join%20operations%20and%20typically%20scale%20horizontally.).

[This](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/04/you-got-nosql-in-mysql-memcach.php) blog in addition to the Wikipedia link, might help you to form an opinion.

Comment: thank you for pin pointing the key issues for the creation of NoSQLS.